# equationsToMatrix: how do I get the values of the variables?

Tags: matlab, matrix, equations

When using equationsToMatrix you solve a set of linear equations as in the example (the solution is included)

```
syms x y z;
[A, b] = equationsToMatrix([x + y - 2*z == 0, x + y + z == 1, 2*y - z + 5 == 0], [x, y, z])

%solution of the equation set

A =
[ 1, 1, -2]
[ 1, 1,  1]
[ 0, 2, -1]

b =
  0
  1
 -5
```

The vector b returns the values of the variables at issue: x,y, and z. However if I type x then MATLAB returns x and not 0, which is the solution of the equation in this case. This also occurs without adding the syms option.

The other problem is that if I type b(1) or b(2), I don't get any value: I would expect b to contain the values of x,y and z.
What I would need is to get something like this in the end

```
b(1) = 0
```

or

```
x = 0
```

What should I do to get the values of x,y,z by just typing x,y,z?

Comment: To solve the system you need to do `ans = A\b`.

Comment: @ja72 done it, but it returns a message of error

Comment: And the error is???...

Comment: If you have a further question please ask it as another question. Don't edit your older questions just to follow up on them.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a way of converting symbolic linear equations into a numeric system by extracting the coefficient matrices. To solve the system you need to do

```
sol = A\b;
```

and now you can use the values in another expression with

`subst(expr, {x,y,z}, {sol(1),sol(2),sol(3));`

for example

```
A =

 1     1    -2
 1     1     1
 0     2    -1

b =

 0
 1
-5

>> A\b

ans =

3.0000
-2.3333
0.3333
```

Comment: I already have b, ie the values of x,y and z. What I can't do is to extract these values from the matrix b, or in other words if I type b(1) I don't get the value of x. In this case b is the matrix of the UNKNOWNS: I have an equation like A*b = C. C is the matrix with only zero values. I have to do b = C/A

Comment: sorry, got the point! I couldn't sort it out immediately as MATLAB had switched off. I wrote sol = b and then expr = [A,b], then just the same as you did. It works.